# Populate data in dynamic cloned select option via ajax success

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, laravel, laravel-blade

I have three select option menu like Department, Sub Department, and Person and a button to clone theme.
I want to populate the sub-department based on the selected Department and Person based on the selected Sub Department.
I can get data via ajax, but unable to append it to second or Sub Department select option

My HTML CODE

```
<input onclick="addRow()" type="button" value="+" style="float: left">
                    <div id="departs" class="row">
                        <table id="clonedtable">
                            <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Department</td>
                                <td>Sub Department</td>
                                <td>Person</td>
                            </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                            <tr class="aaa">
                                <td>
                                    <select id="departments" name="" class="required form-control departments">
                                        <option value="0">--Select Department--</option>
                                        @foreach($department as $dep)
                                            <option value="{{$dep->id}}">{{$dep->department}}</option>
                                        @endforeach
                                    </select>
                                </td>
                                <td class="bbb">
                                    <select id="Sub_departments" class="required form-control Sub_departments">
                                        <option value="0">--Select Sub Department--</option>
                                    </select>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <select id="name" name="name[]" class="required form-control">
                                        <option value="0">--Select Person--</option>
                                        {{--@foreach($name as $names)--}}
                                        {{--<option value="{{$names->id}}">{{$names->name}}</option>--}}
                                        {{--@endforeach--}}
                                    </select>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
```

MY JAVA SCRIPT CODE

```
    var counter = 0;
    function addRow() {
        //copy the table row and clear the value of the input, then append the row to the end of the table
        $("#clonedtable tbody tr:first").clone().find("input").each(function () {
            // $(this).val('');
        }).end().appendTo("#clonedtable");
        counter++;
        // $("#removeclone").removeAttr("disabled");

    };

        $("#clonedtable").on('change','#departments',function () {

            // alert($(this).val());
            $dep_id = $(this).val();
            $(this).closest("td").next("td").find(".Sub_departments option").remove(); // this works fine
            // $(this).closest("td").next("td").find(".Sub_departments option").append('<option value=' +0+ '><--Select Sub Department--> </option>');

            $.ajax({
                url: 'get_sub_departments/'+$dep_id+'',
                type: 'GET',
                data: data,
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                    alert($(this).val());
                    // $(this).closest("td").next("td").find(".Sub_departments option").remove();
                    $(this).closest("td").next("td").find(".Sub_departments").append('<option value=' +0+ '><--Select Sub Department--> </option>'); //this won't work inside ajax but works outside of it
                    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                        $(this).closest("td").next("td").find(".Sub_departments").append('<option value=' + data[i].id + '>' + data[i].sub_department + '</option>'); //this won't work inside ajax but works fine outside
                    }
                }
            });

        });
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution
1: made an array
2:pushed the ajax data to new array
3:And access it outside the ajax
like this

```
        $("#clonedtable").on('change','#departments',function () {
            $dep_id = $(this).val();
            $(this).closest("td").next("td").find(".Sub_departments option").remove(); // this works fine

            $.ajax({
                url: 'get_sub_departments/'+$dep_id+'',
                type: 'GET',
                data: data,
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                    data1 =data; // here added data to data1
                    $(this).closest("td").next("td").find(".Sub_departments").append(`<option value="0"> test</option>`); //this will work
                    alert('success')
                },
                fail:function (data) {
                  alert('failed')
                }

        });
            $(this).closest("td").next("td").find(".Sub_departments").append(`<option value="0"><--Select Sub Department--> </option>`); //this will work
            for (var i = 0; i < data1.length; i++) {
                $(this).closest("td").next("td").find(".Sub_departments").append('<option value=' + data1[i].id + '>' + data1[i].sub_department + '</option>'); //this will work
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to replace this code with this one:

Your Code:

`$(this).closest("td").next("td").find(".Sub_departments option").append('<option value=' +0+` '><--Select Sub Department--> ');

Replaced Code:

`$(this).closest("td").next("td").find(".Sub_departments").append('<option value=' +0+` '><--Select Sub Department--> ');

Answer (score 1):

```
var counter = 0;
            function addRow() {
                //copy the table row and clear the value of the input, then append the row to the end of the table
                $("#clonedtable tbody tr:first").clone().find("input").each(function () {
                    // $(this).val('');
                }).end().appendTo("#clonedtable");
                counter++;
                // $("#removeclone").removeAttr("disabled");

            };

                $("#clonedtable").on('change','#departments',function () {

                    // alert($(this).val());
                    $dep_id = $(this).val();
                    $(this).closest("td").next("td").find(".Sub_departments option").remove(); // this works fine
                    // $(this).closest("td").next("td").find(".Sub_departments option").append('<option value=' +0+ '><--Select Sub Department--> </option>');

                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'get_sub_departments/'+$dep_id+'',
                        type: 'GET',
                        data: data,
                        dataType: 'json',
                        success: function (data) {
                            alert($(this).val());
                            // $(this).closest("td").next("td").find(".Sub_departments option").remove();
                            $(this).closest("td").next("td").find(".Sub_departments").append(`<option value="0"><--Select Sub Department--> </option>`); //this will work
                            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                                $(this).closest("td").next("td").find(".Sub_departments").append(`<option value="${data[i].id}">${data[i].sub_department}</option>`); //this will work
                            }
                        }
                    });

                });
```

Just remove option in $(this).closest("td").next("td").find(".Sub_departments option") because we are appending optionlist to select element and also use tilde symbol to look you code clean.

Comment: I guess you are missing something. check once with hard code.I checked here it's working fine

Comment: i have added picture

Comment: i think it's because dynamic select option

Comment: No. we can you dynamic append with ajax. i add another answer. check once.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <title>test</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <input onclick="addRow()" type="button" value="+" style="float: left">
                <div id="departs" class="row">
                    <table id="clonedtable">
                        <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Department</td>
                            <td>Sub Department</td>
                            <td>Person</td>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                        <tr class="aaa">
                            <td>
                                <select id="departments" name="" class="required form-control departments">
                                    <option value="0">--Select Department--</option>
                                    <option value="1">option1</option>
                                    <option value="2">option2</option>
                                </select>
                            </td>
                            <td class="bbb">
                                <select id="Sub_departments" class="required form-control Sub_departments">
                                    <option value="0">--Select Sub Department--</option>
                                </select>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <select id="name" name="name[]" class="required form-control">
                                    <option value="0">--Select Person--</option>

                                </select>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
        <script>
            var counter = 0;
            function addRow() {
                //copy the table row and clear the value of the input, then append the row to the end of the table
                $("#clonedtable tbody tr:first").clone().find("input").each(function () {
                    // $(this).val('');
                }).end().appendTo("#clonedtable");
                counter++;
                // $("#removeclone").removeAttr("disabled");

            };

                $("#clonedtable").on('change','#departments',function () {

                    // alert($(this).val());
                    $dep_id = $(this).val();
                    $(this).closest("td").next("td").find(".Sub_departments option").remove(); // this works fine
                    // $(this).closest("td").next("td").find(".Sub_departments option").append('<option value=' +0+ '><--Select Sub Department--> </option>');

                    $(this).closest("td").next("td").find(".Sub_departments").append(`<option value="0"> test</option>`); //this will work

                });

        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

check this is working.It'll work with ajax also.

Comment: They all work fine outside the ajax but not inside success function

Comment: Please don't post multiple answers to same question @Amit Sinha.